# Using LittleProxy to intercept, manipulate and forward requests

Tags: java, proxy, http-proxy, little-proxy

It is my first time doing anything with proxies etc. so I dont know how to do this with LittleProxy.
I already set my browser up and downloaded littleproxy-mitm, added it as a mitm and was able to get the proxy itself running but I dont know how to intercept any requests.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Did you read through the READMEs at https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy and https://github.com/ganskef/LittleProxy-mitm? Which step in there didn't work for you?

Comment: Everything works but I dont know how to intercept requests

Comment: My goal is to intercept a request, manipulate it and forward it.